# Restore an page in different Apex application

Tags: oracle-apex

I 'm working with 2 PC's, one of them is the principally PC and the other is the intern's PC, The intern made an app page, in a workspace with the SAME ID and SAME NAME, when the exported file is restored in the principal PC, i got an different application page, there is anyway how i can restore an

Comment: Are you working on the same instance? How was the intern able to create such a scenario in a constraint protected environment? Your question/detail seems incomplete

Answer (score 0):

You can export "as of" x many minutes ago, but do it soon, otherwise your redo will fade out.
http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2012/03/exporting-deleted-apex-applications.html